# multiple ICacheClient implementations with ServiceStack

Tags: session, caching, servicestack

I'm just starting to read about ServiceStack's session and caching mechanisms so I could be missing something. Is there a way to use multiple ICacheClient implementations with ServiceStack?

According to https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions and https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching you can add a session Plugin as follows:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    Plugins.Add(new SessionFeature());
}
```

And you can register a particular ICacheClient implementation like so:

```
container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
```

What I'm thinking is that you might have cases where you need a stateful service that would maintain a great deal of session state for maximum performance, but for more typical caching requirements, you'd want to use something like Redis:

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => 
    new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379"));
container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => 
    (ICacheClient)c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());
```

But is there a way to switch between these? Would you have to create a provider manually (bypassing IoC) and use it for either the in-memory or the Redis caching (using IoC for the other ICacheClient instance)? Or create a wrapper around both ICacheClient implementations and use something like a special key naming pattern to internally switch between using the in-memory vs. Redis cache?

Also, how would you deal with accessing data via ISession? Could you potentially back the ISession with the in-memory ICacheClient while using the Redis one just when you directly refer to your auto-wired ICacheClient property?

Answer (score 3):

Servicestack session state is maintained using the ICacheClient.  You would need to decide which provider you want servicestack to use for caching and set this as you've described - ie Memcached:

```
container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
```

If you wanted to use another type of caching register it in the IOC, giving:

```
container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());  // For servicestack session state

//REDIS for other caching options
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379"));
container.Register<IREDISClient>(c => (IREDISClient)c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetClient());
```

Your different classes would then use the caching provider that is most appropriate by defining the Caching interface that it requires:

```
public ICacheClient Cache { get; set; }
```

or

```
public IREDISClient REDISCache { get; set; }
```

You could make both available in your services by extending the servicestack service class and creating your own appservicebase as demonstrate in the [socialbootstrap project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/ServiceInterface/AppServiceBase.cs).  You could then make both cache models available.

I use REDIS for all caching, it's quick enough for my needs and in a multi-server architecture allows servers to be taken down for maintenance without any loss of user sessions.

I do still have two cache providers through, the standard REDIS Client - wired up to ICacheClient - and the native REDIS client - wired up to IRedisNativeClient.  This is due to the serialisation employed by the standard REDIS client not working with some non-POCO objects that I need to temporarily persist.

Comment: Mythz, got confused by your edits - I've reworked the answer a bit to try and better explain what I meant.

Comment: I've no idea why you're making up interfaces that doesn't exist? This code wont compile.

Comment: No it won't compile, the interface would need to be defined.  I was trying to demonstrate how to have two different cache providers, ensuring the ICacheClient is set to be the one that will be used for session state and a second one that could be used as need within an app whilst still using IOC.

Comment: On reflection Mythz you are spot on, there is no need to make up a new interface.  I've edit the answer to use the existing IREDISClient within the IOC.  Still Learning :)